# Get all Youtube channels associated with one account

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can you get all channels that are from the same google account / mail?
In the Youtube API you can make a reqeust for a list of channels from the autorized account but it only returns main channel.

I'm authorizing with Google Identity Service (oAuth2) and then use GAPI to get the suppose channel list with mine: true.
My account has multiple channels and the list only contains one.